# Skew symmetric matrix of vector triple product

Tags: vectors, skew-symmetric-matrices

Do someone know how to describe the skew symmetric matrix form of $B \times(C\times D)$ vector triple product? I know that $[A\times B]_\times = [A]_\times[B]_\times - [B]_\times[A]_\times$ as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix). I am asking because I have the following:
$$
A\times [B \times (C \times D)]
$$
which I have rewritten in the matrix form:
$$
[A]_\times[B]_\times[C]_\times D
$$
And I need to swap positions and have $[B]_\times$ in the first position, for example $[B]_\times[C]_\times[D]_\times A$, without changing the result. I was thinking of doing so:
$$
A\times [B \times (C \times D)] = -[B \times (C \times D)]\times A
$$
But I need to put that in a matrix form using the skew symmetric matrix, but I don't know how. If someone have a suggestion, I would appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Equivalently, we want an expression $f$ for which $A\times(B\times(C\times D))=B\times f(A,C,D)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rewrite $A\times(B\times(C\times D))$ as $B\times V(A,C,D)$ for some function $V$, it's impossible.

Suppose the contrary. Then $B\cdot(A\times(B\times(C\times D)))=0$ for all $A,B,C,D$. In particular, we would have
$$
1=\mathbf i\cdot(\mathbf j\times(\mathbf i\times(\mathbf k\times\mathbf i)))=0,
$$
which is a contradiction.

Anyway, by [Jacobi's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity) $B\times(C\times D)+C\times(D\times B)+D\times(B\times C)=0$, you may express $B\times(C\times D)$ in terms of $C\times(D\times B)$ and $D\times(B\times C)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there an identity that says:
$$
A \times [B \times (C \times D)] + B \times [A \times (D \times C)] + C \times [D \times (A \times B)] + D \times [C \times (B \times A)] = 0
$$
??

Comment: @WestC Yes, it's true.

Comment: But how is this identity called? Also Jacobi identity?

Comment: @WestC I don't know any name for it, but it shouldn't be considered a generalisation of Jacobi's identity because the expressions are not cyclic here.

Comment: I searched on Google and, according to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity), that identity, as far as I understand, is called  Hall–Witt identity. Is that right?

Comment: @WestC It seems so.