# How can I prove $[r][\omega]^{2}r = -[\omega][r]^2\omega$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, proof-explanation, cross-product, skew-symmetric-matrices

A derivation I am reading from a book requires me to prove
$[r][\omega]^{2}r = -[\omega][r]^2\omega$ .
Now this was part of a larger derivation and hence the book skipped a few intermediary steps and I am not able to reach the RHS from LHS or vice versa.

Here, r and $\omega \in \Re^3$ i.e. they are 3 dimensional vectors. $[r]$ represents the skew symmetric matrix representation of the vector $r$ : $\begin{align}
[r] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & -r_3 & r_2 \\ 
r_3 & 0 &-r_1 \\
 -r_2 & r_1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}   $

This representation has the benefit that the cross product $\vec r \times \vec \omega$ is the same as the matrix and vector multiplication $[r]\cdot\omega$

A few results using this notation: for $a,b \in \Re^3$

- $[a]b = -[b]a$
- $[a] = -[a]^T$
- $[a][b] = ([b][a])^T = [a]^T[b]^T $

Steps the textbook performed to derive the result:

$[r][\omega]^2r = -[r]^T[\omega]^T[r]\omega = -[\omega][r]^2\omega$

My attempt:

$[r][\omega]^2r = [r][\omega][\omega]r = -[r][\omega][r]\omega = -[r]^T[\omega]^T[r]\omega$ = ?(How to proceed)

Is there anything I am missing? An insight in the right direction will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to prove the identity using the [vector triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Triple_product_expansion) formula $a\times(b\times c)=(a\cdot c)b-(a\cdot b)c$:
\begin{aligned}
&r\times\left[\omega\times(\omega\times r)\right]+\omega\times\left[r\times(r\times\omega)\right]\\
&=r\times\left[(\omega\cdot r)\omega-(\omega\cdot\omega)r\right]+\omega\times\left[(r\cdot\omega)r-(r\cdot r)\omega\right]\\
&=(\omega\cdot r)r\times\omega-(\omega\cdot\omega)r\times r+(r\cdot\omega)\omega\times r-(r\cdot r)\omega\times\omega\\
&=0.
\end{aligned}
The identity in question can also be viewed as a special case of [Hall-Witt identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity#Related_identities), which someone happened to have [asked about](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3779262/skew-symmetric-matrix-of-vector-triple-product/3779294#comment7782769_3779294) yesterday.

Comment: Thanks! That clears it up!